# TabbedPage with Shell (FlyoutBehavior="disabled") show blank space above tab in Android and bar with Page Title in iOS How to remove it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, maui, tabbedpage, xamarin-shell

I'm experimenting with TabbedPage and Shell in MAUI to create Horizontally scrollable tabs. I have got the expected behavior but in Android it shows a blank white space at top of Tabs and in iOS it shows Bar with a title of Tab Selected. I have attached a screenshot of Android.

**Any one know how to remove it?**

### Code I have created:

> Note: here page: are Content pages I have created in TabPages folder in project

#### MainPage.xaml

```cs
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Tyler.Energov.Mobile.EH.UI.InspectionOverview.InspectionOverviewPage"
            xmlns:page="clr-namespace:Tyler.Energov.Mobile.EH.UI.InspectionOverview.TabPages"
            Title="InspectionOverviewPage">
    
    <Shell FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" FlyoutHeaderBehavior="Default">
        <FlyoutItem Title="Abc">
            <Tab>
                
                <ShellContent Title="Parent record" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:ParentRecordPage}"/>
                <ShellContent Title="Additional info" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:AdditionalInfoPage}"/>

                <ShellContent Title="Contacts" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:ContactsPage}"/>
                <ShellContent Title="Previous inspections" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:PreviousInspectionPage}"/>

                <ShellContent Title="Attachments" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:AttachmentsPage}"/>
                
            </Tab>
        </FlyoutItem>
    </Shell>
</TabbedPage>
```

---

#### Tab Background color and Text color I have updated from the Style.xaml

```css
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightGray}, Dark={StaticResource DarkGray}}" />
</Style>
```

---

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Means you need a github repo with demo?

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: You can check it here: https://github.com/divyesh008/maui_tabbedpage.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Shell` as the root element.

I created a demo and achieved this function.
You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="TabedPageDemo.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabedPageDemo"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:TabedPageDemo.Pages"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Test"
            Icon="icon.png">
            <ShellContent Title="Parent Record"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:DiscoverPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Additional Info"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AdditionalInfoPage}" />

            <ShellContent Title="Contacts"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:EpisodeDetailPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Previous Inspection"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:CategoriesPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Attachements"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:DiscoverPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Updated Inspection"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:ShowDetailPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Inspector Profile"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:EpisodeDetailPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="About us"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:CategoriesPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

Comment: Tabs background color not changes in iOS, do you have any idea about how to change tabs background color?